# Forbidden 403 for parse-server on version 2.2.24 and above

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

I want to update my server with the latest version of parse server, but I am running into the issue where are all the calls send back a 403 Forbidden.

The exact same calls work on 2.2.23 and below but not on 2.2.24 and above. I am using parse for an iOS app, where I am using SDK 1.14.

Notes on the setup:

- added VERBOSE environment variable, logs correctly on 2.2.23 but nothing on 2.2.24
- running the server in localhost with node v6.9.1 installed.
- pointing to a DB in mLab with mongod version: 3.0.12.
- using express "~4.14.x"

Reviewed issues:

- https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/508 Where the
  user was able to fix it by starting from scratch with
  parse-server-example. I have tested this, using my ParseServer
  instantiation and copying over the cloud code, I am having the same
  issue.
- https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1017 Was about
  passing the X-Parse-Application-Id, which I am doing since it is
  working for 2.2.23 but not for 2.2.24 and higher

Has anybody experienced something similar? Any hint on what I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: in your response body do you see something like: "unauthorized" ?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing unauthorized in the body

Comment: so this is either appId or masterKey is wrong.. please double check it

Comment: Hi Ran, thanks for your answer. App Id and Master Key are correct, everything is working on 2.2.23 but not on 2.2.24. So it must be something else

Comment: you are using oauth maybe ?

Comment: a 403 normally means that the app id that was sent (none) is unauthorized (forbidden). can you test it by posting to it via postman? sending those 2 heads.

Comment: also try the latest version and see if that resolves it 2.3.1

Comment: @RanHassid I am have facebook login as an option, but the issue appears no matter if I login with normal user+pass or facebook

Comment: @SnakeBlisken thanks for your answer. I am using Charles Proxy (kind of similar to Postman) to see what is being sent. I can see the headers being correctly sent with the correct App Id as well. I have tried 2.3.1, actually I began trying this one and I have been testing all versions backwards till hitting one were it woks, which is 2.2.23. So I am guessing there is something different in 2.2.24

Comment: @RanHassid just to specify my comment about facebook login. The issue appears no matter if the session was started with user+pass or facebook. In the means of: login done with 2.2.23 and then launching again with 2.2.24 no data is being retrieved. Login with 2.2.24 doesn't work, since none of the calls works with 2.2.24

Comment: Ok can you please try to update to 2.3.1 which is the latest release and retest it?

Comment: I have tried 2.3.1 (see comment above) and I am having the same issue.

Comment: there is a chance to get an access to your parse server instance?